# How to get data from django celery tasks

Tags: python, django, scheduled-tasks, celery

```
# In tasks.py file
from __future__ import absolute_import

from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

# In views.py
def home(request):
    context = {
        'add': tasks.add.delay(5,2)

    }

    return render(request, "home.html", context)

# In home.html
<h1>{{ add }}</h1>
```

Instead of 7 appearing on home.html I get giberish that looks like this:313e-44fb-818a-f2b2d824a46b.  What can I do to get the data from my tasks.py file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply change:

```
def home(request):
    context = {
        'add': tasks.add.delay(5,2)

    }

    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

to:

```
def home(request):
    context = {
        'add': tasks.add.delay(5,2).get()

    }

    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

This will be processed by Celery too.

Ading `.delay()` You setting task as asynchronous and You receiving `task_id`.

More info in doc: [Calling Tasks](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#basics)

Comment: Awesome, that worked!  YESSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSs.  I'll accept your answer in 6 mins.

Comment: But remember that You shoudn't wait for result ! Look at: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#avoid-launching-synchronous-subtasks